# Show camera on only half of the screen

Tags: ios5, camera

I'd like to display the camera view on only half the screen on both iPhone and iPad. I've done a lot of searching, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Thats not a big deal first of all tell me ... u r writing code for iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: What u need in the remaining portion?add a camera overlay to half of your screen.Follow this tutorial for adding a camera overlay.You can add buttons or backgrounds or images or anything else as the overlay.

Comment: I have created universal app...For iphone and ipad both

Comment: @annu - In another half portion I want to put lables and textboxes

Comment: sorry see this link http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821

Comment: @MeghaMishty let me know if u hav any querries..and accept the answer if u find it useful..:)

Comment: CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 27.0);
imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = translate;

Comment: The main line of code is    picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this .. if this is not help full for you or facing any problem, tell me i will provide you some other sample code ..

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;

controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                  delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
             animations:^{
                 controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
             }
             completion:nil
 ];

[imagePickerController release];
```