# Show Camera in half of the screen in portrait when rest of the application is in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, camera

I have my application for iPad and its in landscape mode only . I want to open camera in portrait mode in upper half of the screen, and in the lower half i want to add some IBOutlets. FYI in projetc's setting supported interface orientations are Landscape left and landscape right only.

I tried the solution given on link [Show camera on only half of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407860/show-camera-on-only-half-of-the-screen/17875011#17875011) as it is and in didfinishPickingMediaWithInfo i removed the imagePickerController.view

1. Camera opens up in full screen :(
2. How can i open camera in portrait.
3. didfinishPickingMediaWithInfo returns null in UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage.
   Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you won't be able to achieve desired behaviour with UIImagePickerController since it is a special kind of controller. 
You can take a look in media capture guide. You can then create AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer with your own size and present it how you like though you will need to write your own code for capturing images.

This is the Apple doc for that. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

This is a good presentation with code snippets.
http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/capturing-stills-sounds-and-scenes-with-av-foundation

You might also find this question useful.
[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer orientation - need landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075300/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-orientation-need-landscape)

Comment: yes i went through the documentation of apple. AVCam is the apple sample code to use in this case.